# Image Overflow at the Top?

Tags: html, css

I have a website I am working on and been trying to get the image to overflow at the top and align at the bottom.

http://mytempsite.net/raven/

Right now the DIV is 500PX tall and when the image goes bigger than that it's overflow is hidden at the bottom. The problem is it makes the images look really weird. I need it the images to stretch cause I am in the process of making the site responsive, the images I know get blurry but these are just temp images.

My question is, Is there a way that the bottom of the image gets aligned and like fixed to the bottom of the DIV and then when it gets stretched bigger it overflows at the top of the page like negatively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're trying to make the bottom of the image displayed instead of the top? If that's the case, on the selector `#myGallery img` change the position the image to the bottom instead of the top.

```
#myGallery img {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;  // change this from top to bottom
    width: 100%;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: that worked, dunno why that didn't come to my mind. DUH!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing the height from your DIV, and removing position: absolute from your images, because you need the images' height to define the height of the DIV, no matter the size.

On responsive slideshows, I've started doing the following CSS:

```
.slide {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -100%;
}
```

This allows you to stack them on each other, like absolute positioning does, but the DIV responds to your slides' height.

You also have the white fade at the bottom, though, and I presume this is part of the reason for your question—that you would like to have that fade work on smaller views.

For that, img#fadeimage should have `position: absolute; bottom: 0; height: 100%`, but you also may need to build your image so there's more empty space at top.

Comment: I don't want the DIV to respond to the height of the image since the faded look into white is a separate image to get that look. and that would cause issues.